# How to add new URLs to serve my Google App Engine Application programatically?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-admin-sdk

I have created an application that runs in GAE where users can create online stores. They can set up their own domain for the store. I verify the domain using Google Site Verification API:
https://developers.google.com/site-verification/v1/webResource

In order to serve the application in their domain, I also need to add a new URL defining a subdomain (i.e. www). I am currently doing this step manually, but I would like to do it programatically.

Is there a Google API to add new URLs to serve an app?